# Maven Surefire Plugin + Spock 2: additional “test case” in the report

Tags: spock, maven-surefire-plugin

With Spock upgrade to `2.4-M1-groovy-3.0` we found out that test reports for our data driven tests (= using `@Unroll` Spock annotation) contain an additional "test case" and also counts the time of this "test case" to the total which means the total time doubles.

I searched the docs and it seems to be Spock 2's default feature to show the test results for data driven tests in a tree (e.g. when run in IDE) showing the tests hierarchy while Maven Surfire can probably show only a flat list:

[image: Example: Flat list vs tree]

Hence there is this umbrella "test case" which is quite confusing. Would anyone know how the get rid of the additional line in the report?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spock 2.0 is reporting an extra test for data-driven tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68490737/spock-2-0-is-reporting-an-extra-test-for-data-driven-tests). Spock 2.x is an engine running[on top of the JUnit 5 platform. This way to group parametrised tests are a standard JUnit 5 feature. It is the same for `@ParameterizedTest` tests in JUnit Jupiter. If your test report tool does not support that, maybe you can upgrade it or raise a bug.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, this is a bit different issue. It looks to me the problem is in maven-surefire-plugin configuration which generates the xml file with the report, but so far, I haven't been able to find the right setup.

Comment: How about Leonard's interesting suggestion then?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you have to use this bit of config in your [pom.xml](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/c9951e87aadb676441c80c54793e2770fa063ab0/pom.xml#L47-L54)

```xml
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
<configuration>
          <statelessTestsetReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5Xml30StatelessReporter">
            <disable>false</disable>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
            <usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>true</usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>
            <usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>
            <usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>
          </statelessTestsetReporter>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you, `statelessTestsetReporter` has an effect on how the test case names are put together in the report, however, no matter what I set in its configuration, the additional "test case" remains in the report.